# Mounting the DEV@cloud Private WebDav Repository fails

Tags: maven-3, cloudbees

I'm using the private repository to store my own custom `settings.xml`. When i try to use it i get the following log message:

```
$ /usr/bin/tenant-isolate sudo /opt/jenkins/sbin/mount-webdav https://repository-laures.forge.cloudbees.com/private laures alert
mountpoint: /private/laures: No such file or directory
```

when my buildjob later wants to access my custom `settings.xml` i get an exception:

```
Executing Maven:  -B -f /scratch/jenkins/workspace/JacksonLegacyIntrospector/pom.xml -gs /private/laures/settings.xml clean verify site emma:emma
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:100)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:66)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.cli.MavenExecutionRequestsBuilderException: The specified global settings file does not exist: /private/laures/settings.xml
    at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.getMavenExecutionRequest(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:148)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.getMavenExecutionRequest(Maven3Launcher.java:94)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:77)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: The specified global settings file does not exist: /private/laures/settings.xml
    at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.settings(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.getMavenExecutionRequest(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:126)
    ... 20 more
```

I was following the cloudbees guide: https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Sharing+Files+with+Build+Executors

Did i do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This job is validating pull-requests. A malicious user could hack your build script in a pull request and extract confidential informations from your account.

To prevent this, CloudBees run such a build using `tenant-isolate` script. This prevent /private to get mounted, this is intentional - but not nicely reported on the web UI.

Comment: i removed the pull request builder feature from my build-job and everything is fine. so it looks like i can not have a custom settings.xml AND the pull-request builder at the same time.

Comment: indeed. Validating pull request anyway suppose you expect contributors to be able to build your project, so should not require additional secrets/config but the one in SCM

Comment: true. i was still very happy that i did not have to maintain multiple build-jobs for my project so far. looks like i will require at least one for pull-requests and one for all the rest (metrics, release, ...).